# wxPython progress bar

Tags: python, wxpython

I can't use [`wx.ProgressDialog`](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.ProgressDialog-class.html) because I need to add extra contents to the dialog box (a pause button and information about what is currently being processed).  Is there a control for just the progress bar that I can use in my own dialog box?

I could of course draw something simple myself, but since the program needs to run on Mac OS X, Windows, and Linux it would be better if the progress bars had a native look.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about wxGauge which displays a horizontal or vertical bar?
http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.Gauge-class.html

More complete C++ doc:
http://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.6/wx_wxgauge.html#wxgauge

Answer (score 2):

You could always create your own derivative of wx.Dialog and using a sizer, add in the widgets you require.

Here's one from my program, for example:

```
class ProgressDialog(wx.Dialog):
    """
    Shows a Progres Gauge while an operation is taking place. May be cancellable
    which is possible when converting pdf/ps
    """
    def __init__(self, gui, title, to_add=1, cancellable=False):
        """Defines a gauge and a timer which updates the gauge."""
        wx.Dialog.__init__(self, gui, title=title,
                          style=wx.CAPTION)
        self.gui = gui
        self.count = 0
        self.to_add = to_add
        self.timer = wx.Timer(self)
        self.gauge = wx.Gauge(self, range=100, size=(180, 30))
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.gauge, 0, wx.ALL, 10)

        if cancellable:
            cancel = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_CANCEL, _("&Cancel"))
            cancel.SetDefault()
            cancel.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.on_cancel)
            btnSizer = wx.StdDialogButtonSizer()
            btnSizer.AddButton(cancel)
            btnSizer.Realize()
            sizer.Add(btnSizer, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER | wx.TOP | wx.BOTTOM, 10)

        self.SetSizer(sizer)
        sizer.Fit(self)
        self.SetFocus()

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.on_timer, self.timer)
        self.timer.Start(30)


    def on_timer(self, event):
        """Increases the gauge's progress."""
        self.count += self.to_add
        self.gauge.SetValue(self.count)
        if self.count > 100:
            self.count = 0


    def on_cancel(self, event):
        """Cancels the conversion process"""
        # do whatever
```